# Dynamically passing the column name as well the values in python mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, flask

This is the following code

```
pythonlist = ['Name','Mno']
datalist = ["qwerty",'234']
sql = "SELECT " + ",".join(pythonlist) + " FROM data WHERE name = '"+ "','".join(datalist) + "' INTO OUTFILE filename"
print(sql)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
SELECT Name,Mno FROM data WHERE Name= 'qwerty','234'
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
SELECT Name,Mno FROM data WHERE Name = 'qwerty' and Mno = 234
```

Do note the removal of quotations marks in 'mno'.

The reason I am doing this is due because the column names, as well as values corresponding it to, will change frequently

Comment: make it dictionary instead of list , like so  - `{'Name': 'qwerty' , 'Mno' : '234'}` . using list for such operation is not looking fine.

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat Will you be able to send me the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code :

```
queryparams = {'Name': 'qwerty', 'Mno': '234'}

and_clause = []
[and_clause.append(' %s = %s ') for k,v in queryparams.items()]
and_clause_str = ' and '.join(and_clause)

sql = 'SELECT %s FROM data WHERE ' + and_clause_str

params = [','.join(queryparams.keys())]
for k,v in queryparams.items():
  params.append(str(k))
  params.append(str(v))
print(sql)
print(params)
cursor.execute(sql, params=tuple(params))
```

This works if you add 10/20 more items to dictionary . 
Aswell as prevents `SQL-injection` : Using `params` to pass values instead of `string-concatenation` .

Comment: Just go through `SQL-injection` topic if you don't know about it . The code you have shown in the question is vulnerable to those attacks .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = {'Name': 'qwerty' , 'Mno' : '234'}

sql = "SELECT " + ", ".join(data.keys()) + " FROM data WHERE " + str(list(data.keys())[0]) + "  = '" + \
      str(data[list(data.keys())[0]]) + "' and " +\
      str(list(data.keys())[1]) + " = " + str(data[list(data.keys())[1]])

print(sql)
```

Comment: appreciate it, but if I increase the dictionary by adding one more value then I would have to increase data list too which is not needed in my scenario

Comment: appreciate it, but this snippet won't work if I add another value to dictionary say for example 'Data':  'JSON' I would have to code that part rather than it adjusts itself regardless of values passed.